# discord.py bot didn't respond to message in server chat only in DM

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I try this code but it's always respond in private not in public
I have been given admin to the bot but still not working

## code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import sys

def clear():
  if sys.platform == "linux":
    os.system("clear")
  if sys.platform == "windows":
    os.system("cls")
  

intent = discord.Intents.default()
intent.members = True
client =commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents = intent, description="<desc>")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"bot: {client.user} is ready")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f"Member, {member} Joined")

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
  print(f"{member}, left")

@client.command()
async def hi(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Hi")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  await client.process_commands(message)

client.run("MTEyMTQ2NTgxNDkxMTAyOTM0OA.G1zR4J.KLQmyRRAb6gj7m8qzLtHO8HtfAWNje0dGgXznE")

clear()
```

that code bellows didn't work as want

Comment: Just noticed the bot token in the code. You should reset the token from the discord dev portal, so people don't abuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable the message content intent in order to allow the bot to read the message. Depending on the way you have set it, you might have to enable it through the dev portal and/or give perms to the bot in the server as well. The following lines should solve the issue by enabling the message_content intent.

```
...
intent = discord.Intents.default()
intent.members = True
intents.message_content = True
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much,the line (intent.message_content = True) makes it work ok, but why the most of youtube toturials didn't use it and the code work correctly ?

Comment: What do you mean by "but the line (intents.message_content = True)". I think it's just a translation issue, but if not, please explain so I can correct the answer or provide a better explanation for it.

Comment: @3bd2lra7man Most likely the Youtube tutorials you are watching are very, very outdated. Try to look for more recent ones, or just refer to the official documentation / examples.